# Custom fields in Many2Many JoinTable

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have this model with a custom JoinTable:

```
type Person struct {
  ID        int
  Name      string
  Addresses []Address `gorm:"many2many:person_addresses;"`
}

type Address struct {
  ID   uint
  Name string
}

type PersonAddress struct {
  PersonID  int
  AddressID int
  Home      bool
  CreatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt
}
```

How is it possible to assign a value to the `Home` field when creating a new `Person`?

Answer (score 5):

### Method 1

From what I can see in the docs, here's a clean way you might currently do this:

```golang
DB.SetupJoinTable(&Person{}, "Addresses", &PersonAddress{})

addr1 := Address{Name: "addr1"}
DB.Create(&addr1)

addr2 := Address{Name: "addr2"}
DB.Create(&addr2)

person := Person{Name: "jinzhu"}
DB.Create(&person)

// Add an association with default values (i.e. Home = false)
DB.Model(&person).Association("Addresses").Append(&addr1)

// Add an association with custom values
DB.Create(&PersonAddress{
    PersonID:  person.ID,
    AddressID: addr2.ID,
    Home:      true,
})
```

Here we're using the actual join table model to insert a row with the values we want.

We can also filter queries for the association:

```golang
addr := Address{}
// Query association with filters on join table
DB.Where("person_addresses.home = true").
    Model(&person).
    Association("Addresses").
    Find(&addr)
```

### Method 2

Here's a more magical way, by (ab)using the `Context` to pass values to a `BeforeSave` hook, in addition to the `SetupJoinTable` code from above:

```golang
func (pa *PersonAddress) BeforeSave(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    home, ok := tx.Statement.Context.Value("home").(bool)
    if ok {
        pa.Home = home
    }
    return nil
}

// ...

DB.WithContext(context.WithValue(context.Background(), "home", true)).
    Model(&person).
    Association("Addresses").
    Append(&addr2)
```

This method feels icky to me, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you can find this point in the official documents of the GROM, you can implement some methods for each table(struct).

You can implement BeforeCreate() and/or AfterCreate() methods for your join table, gorm will check that method on time!

You can do anything inside those methods to achieve your goal.
[here](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html) you will find the full documentation.

enjoy ;)

Comment: I can implement BeforeCreate() on the join table, in order to set the Home variable, but I don’t understand how to pass the value of Home to BeforeCreate() Hook.

Comment: There is a method to handle that, you can use this method and implement a handler to handle what you want.
DB.SetJoinTableHandler()

Comment: With implementing the JoinTableHandlerInterface, you will be able to create your own methods to apply the CRUD on your data.
You ar welcome for ask me for the example if you are not familiar with that.