# Go gorm creating many to many relationship using customised table and extra data

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to achieve a join between two models using gorm and a customised table. On this customised table I would like to store extra information about the joined models.

As per the [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Customize-JoinTable) I have the following,

```
func init() {
    database.DB.SetupJoinTable(&Foo{}, "Bar", &FooBar{})
}

type Foo struct {
    UUID      uuid.UUID `json:"uuid" gorm:"type:uuid;primaryKey;"`
    SomeValue string    `json:"someValue"`
    Bars      []Bar     `json:"bars" gorm:"many2many:foo_bars"`
}

type Bar struct {
    UUID      uuid.UUID `json:"uuid" gorm:"type:uuid;primaryKey;"`
    SomeValue string    `json:"someValue"`
}

type FooBar struct {
    FooUUID    uuid.UUID `json:"foo" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    BarUUID    uuid.UUID `json:"bar" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ExtraValue string    `json:"extraValue"`
}
```

The above creates a schema as I would expect. The problem is when trying to persist this relationship and set extra data needed to `FooBar`. The docs provide documentation on [appending](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Append-Associations) relationships directly from Foo to Bar, but not adding data to this customised table.

The documentation states:

> JoinTable can be a full-featured model

So I would expect this to be possible.

Is this possible using gorm?
How can I create and save this relationship with additional information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually very simple, the fact that `FooBar` is a full-featured model means you can use it to interact with the join table directly the same way that any other model can:

```golang
// assuming we have a Foo foo and Bar bar

// read
links := []FooBar{}
db.Where(FooBar{FooUUID: foo.UUID, BarUUID: bar.UUID}).Find(&links)

// create
link := FooBar{FooUUID: foo.UUID, BarUUID: bar.UUID, ExtraValue: "foobar"}
db.Create(&link)

// update
link.ExtraValue = "foobarbaz"
db.Save(&link)

// delete
db.Delete(&link)
```

But to do all this requires you to treat the join table as a separate model. For example you shouldn't expect to be able to extract the `ExtraValue` when doing regular Associations operations on Foo, because there is literally no space on the `[]Bar` field to put the value. Similar goes for saving the `ExtraValue`, unless you do some special trickery with Hooks (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65290514/415628) for more on this).